# php 5.5 memory leak when using "continue 2" inside two foreach loops?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, foreach, continue

I just came across a strange memory leak issue. I managed to track the problem down to the following code:

```
<?php
$data=array();
for($c=0; $c<32768; $c++)
    $data[$c]=array(1, 2, 3);
$filter=array(1, 2, 3);

for($kc=0; $kc<25600; $kc++)
{
    $cm=memory_get_usage(true);
    $pm=memory_get_peak_usage(true);
    echo "<b>loop $kc: current_memory: $cm, peak_memory: $pm...</b><br>";
    flush();

    foreach($data as $entry)
        foreach($filter as $pattern)
            continue 2;
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
loop 0: current_memory: 12582912, peak_memory: 12582912...
loop 1: current_memory: 20709376, peak_memory: 20709376...
loop 2: current_memory: 28835840, peak_memory: 28835840...
loop 3: current_memory: 36962304, peak_memory: 36962304...
loop 4: current_memory: 45088768, peak_memory: 45088768...
loop 5: current_memory: 53215232, peak_memory: 53215232...
loop 6: current_memory: 61341696, peak_memory: 61341696...
loop 7: current_memory: 69468160, peak_memory: 69468160...
loop 8: current_memory: 77594624, peak_memory: 77594624...
loop 9: current_memory: 85721088, peak_memory: 85721088...
loop 10: current_memory: 93847552, peak_memory: 93847552...
loop 11: current_memory: 101974016, peak_memory: 101974016...
loop 12: current_memory: 110100480, peak_memory: 110100480...
loop 13: current_memory: 118226944, peak_memory: 118226944...
loop 14: current_memory: 126353408, peak_memory: 126353408...
loop 15: current_memory: 134479872, peak_memory: 134479872...
loop 16: current_memory: 142606336, peak_memory: 142606336...
loop 17: current_memory: 151257088, peak_memory: 151257088...
loop 18: current_memory: 159383552, peak_memory: 159383552...
loop 19: current_memory: 167510016, peak_memory: 167510016...
loop 20: current_memory: 175636480, peak_memory: 175636480...
loop 21: current_memory: 183762944, peak_memory: 183762944...
loop 22: current_memory: 191889408, peak_memory: 191889408...
loop 23: current_memory: 200015872, peak_memory: 200015872...
loop 24: current_memory: 208142336, peak_memory: 208142336...
loop 25: current_memory: 216268800, peak_memory: 216268800...
loop 26: current_memory: 224395264, peak_memory: 224395264...
loop 27: current_memory: 232521728, peak_memory: 232521728...
loop 28: current_memory: 240648192, peak_memory: 240648192...
loop 29: current_memory: 248774656, peak_memory: 248774656...
loop 30: current_memory: 256901120, peak_memory: 256901120...
loop 31: current_memory: 265027584, peak_memory: 265027584...
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes) in xxx
```

When I remove the "continue 2" statement and use a simple "break" or "continue", the memory usage stays constant.
Can anyone confirm this strange behavior?
Did I find a memory leak bug in php 5.5?
Using php-cli doesn't show this strange behavior. Only using php as mod_php inside apache shows this behavior.

**My System:**

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.5.11-2 (cli) (built: Apr  8 2014 11:42:22) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

$ apache2ctl status
Apache Server Status for localhost (via ::1)

   Server Version: Apache/2.4.9 (Debian)
          mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 PHP/5.5.11-2
          mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2

   Server MPM: prefork
   Server Built: Mar 29 2014 21:52:01
```

I'm on current Debian testing (Jessie).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tested your code on local and [viper7](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZD4xMI) and not getting no leaks.

Comment: Not seeing any evidence for any version on [3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org/oAPpg#tabs) though they considered it abusive of their resources... sorry 3v4l guys

Comment: Well, thats very strange. I don't know what is so special with my php version. OK, I just tested my code in php-cli --> No memory leak. I'm using apache 2.4.9. (Updated my question and included my apache version information).

Comment: Can you disable Zend OPcache? I've had trouble with it before (did not notice changes in some used files).

Comment: @LeventePánczél YES! that's it! I disabled the opcache and everything behaves as expected. The update from PHP 5.4 to 5.5 overwrote my php.ini and this seems to have enabled the opcache. Thanks for this hint! Do you want to write an answer, so that I can accept it? :)

Comment: the cron-expression lib/project seems to have the same issue
https://github.com/mtdowling/cron-expression/issues/50

Comment: i was banging my head since 1 week to get the root cause of memory leak in my application, i have check each line hundreds of time but didn't find anything suspicious, then i thought about "continue 2" line and search leads me to this page... hmm.. thats f**king bug spoiled my entire week.  looks like I'm not alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### WAIT !!

You should not disable opcache: as well as caching, opcache performs optimization.

Optimization means that opcache *changes the compiled opcodes*.

I am certain that it is the case that tuning optimization will show you where the bug is introduced, this will mean you can create a bug report at bugs.php.net and we have a chance of fixing the problem for everyone.

Please take the time to do this, please.

### Tuning Optimization

Opcache has several optimization passes, https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/962e54c38b155f896b00

Configuring which passes run is a matter of changing `opcache.optimization_level` in your configuration, this is a bitmask, by default `0xffffffff`.

If you need help debugging visit #php.pecl on EFnet.

*Note: to have opcache enabled in php-cli, change `opcache.enable_cli` to `1`, this will allow you to test in console, the same behaviour should display itself*

Comment: Ok...I'll try. What entry in the bitmask corresponds to what optimization pass? Pass 1 has 0x00000001, pass 2 0x00000002 and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record the "continue 2" bug is verified still under 5.5 and 5.6.3 (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65743). One work around is to utilize the 'goto-hack' and not continue but go 'back' to a defined label in the first foreach... i know, f*gly but works (*with* opcache)

Comment: And now the bug is fixed, see this commit: http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=aa394e70ff8cda63ee4382d2488d80936e5122dc That will hopefully be included in the upcoming versions 5.5.21 and 5.6.5

Comment: Yep, fixed in those versions, as seen in the changelog: http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.21